# Determining order of traversal of a sequence

Tags: c++, list, stl

I have a list of elements from 1 to 30 in ascending order. 
The list may or may not contain all the 30 elements. You can start 
traversing the list from any point and once you reach an end, you can jump 
and resume the traversal from the other end, i.e. something along the 
lines of a circular queue.

Given two consecutive elements (by position, may or may not by value), 
is it possible to determine the direction of traversal, i.e. beginning to 
end, or the other way?

Note: You don't have access to the list's indices and are only given 
the values at any instant.

I can do this with three values, but not two.

Comment: Care to tell why this was downvoted?

Comment: I am not the one downvoted, but the reason would be that this is not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to determine the direction of traversal given only two elements. Your conditions allow the following list: `[1, 30]`.

You're now given two consecutive elements: `1, 30`. Did you start at `1` then travel to the right to reach `30`, or did you travel to the left and wrap around to reach `30`? It's impossible to tell.

Comment: That is precisely what I wanted to know. So, if I were to do that using a third element, and I am not given one, by choosing which value, along with the two values I am given, would I be able to fulfil the logic?

Comment: With a list `[1, 30]` you can't tell the direction with any number of elements: starting from `1` either way results in `1 - 30 - 1 - 30 - 1`.... With a one-item list `[3]` it is `3 - 3 - 3 - 3 -` despite the direction....

Comment: @thenoGk I've no idea what that second sentence is trying to say.

Comment: @Adam: I am given only two values. They are consecutive by index. What should be the third value that would enable me to determine the direction?

Comment: you need three values from a list of at least three elements.

Comment: Done. That compliments a previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want with just two values fetched from a list. You need three consecutive values, additionally there must be at least 3 items in the list (see my comment under the answer by @Adam).